# PrestaShop don't import groups and image url's for product

Tags: csv, import, prestashop

Re-read many topics on this issue, but have not found anything sensible

In general, I have the following problem.
Use a version of PrestaShop ™ 1.5.3.1

I create csv file as a csv file for import into the demo, proposed by PrestaShop

When i import csv, the two fields are not imported.
Categories (x, y, z ..)
Images Url (x, y, z)

I know that now instead of the ID must include the name of the group.
I filled the image to the server in the images folder in the root directory

### Here is an example of filling each field

```
Categories (x, y, z ..)
Home, iPhone 5

Images Url (x, y, z)
http://commpot.ru/images/iphone-204-20black.jpg
```

---

After import, I get the goods without images, as well as the category is Home, instead of the Home, iPhone 5

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the category problem by using the category numbers instead of their names.
For the images you need to check your permissions on the img/p folder are set to at least 755 or maybe 777 if 755 deosn't work.